# Error adding folder to Firestore: Function collection() cannot be called with an empty path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I was trying to make a "AddFolderButton" in a modal of my project so what I wanted was that after adding i click on the button it should update the name and userId in the firebase cloud.
But It shows Error as:
Error adding folder to Firestore: Function collection() cannot be called with an empty path.

Below is my firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    //creds
})


export const db = getFirestore(app);

export const database = {
  folders: collection(db, 'folders'),
  files: collection(db, 'files'),
  formatDoc: (doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }),
  getCurrentTimestamp: serverTimestamp(),
};

export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const auth = app.auth()
export default app
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faFolderPlus } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { database, db } from "../../firebase";
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import {
    getFirestore,
    collection,
    getDocs,
    addDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default function AddFolderButton({ currentFolder }) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();

    function openModal() {
        setOpen(true);
    }

    function closeModal() {
        setOpen(false);
    }

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            
            console.log("Database folders:", database.folders);
            const folderRef = await addDoc(collection(database.folders), {
                name: name,                
                userId: currentUser.uid,
                createdAt: database.getCurrentTimestamp(),
            });

            console.log(folderRef.id);
            setName("");
            closeModal();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error adding folder to Firestore:", error.message);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={openModal} variant="outline-success" size="sm">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFolderPlus} />
            </Button>
            <Modal show={open} onHide={closeModal}>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label>Folder Name</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                required
                                value={name}
                                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={closeModal}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="success" type="submit">
                            Add Folder
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Form>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}
```

Above is my AddFolderButton.js

At first the userId was being updated in the firebase but now the same error consoles out

Comment: Your `database.folders` returns `collection`, then why do you again want to wrap it in side the `collection` in the `addDoc`? I meant - `addDoc(collection(database.folders)`. Doesn't seem to be right!

Comment: Thanks Guru It was really a helpful question. WHat i did now was `addDoc((database.folders), {
                //code
            });` and now it is working

Comment: Good to know your issue is resolved! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you had let us know which call to `collection()` the error is coming from.

That said, I suspect it is coming from:

```js
collection(database.folders)
```

because `collection()` takes 2 parameters but you are only providing it with one.  You need to provide it with a `Firestore` object, typically the one you get from `getFirestore()`

Comment: Iam new to these things, Can you help me and guide me how to let you know the error coming from. Imean is there any way?

Comment: Typically along with the error message there is a Stack Trace.  That stack trace should indicate the stack of functions being called, the file and line number of each  point of each function in the call stack.

If there  isn't a stack trace (there should be), then another approach is to put `console.log()` statements (with unique log messages) throughout your code to determine which parts of your code got executed and which parts didn't.  The first part that did NOT get called means that an exception was thrown before getting to that call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a very insightful comment of Guruprasad and an answer by Greg I found out the answer is that When using the addDoc function, you don't need to pass the collection function again for the collection reference. The addDoc function expects a reference to a collection, and database.folders is already a reference to the "folders" collection.

Here's the corrected handleSubmit function in your AddFolderButton component:

```
 const folderRef = await addDoc(database.folders, {
            name: name,
            userId: currentUser.uid,
            
        });
```